# Enviar un formulario luego de comprobar un checkbox en html con jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html

Estoy trabajando con un formulario de "compra" en el cual tengo, ademas de muchos inputs, dos en particular con radios que son Pago en efectivo y Pago con tarjeta. Cuando mi comprador seleccione Pago con efectivo y de click en Enviar debe aparecerle (en mi caso) el template de confirmacion donde tiene los datos del vendedor. En caso de que presione "Pago con tarjeta" no debe, al enviar, aparecerle este template sino... continuar con la validacion siguiente en el cual completar los datos de la tarjeta... y luego si, esta todo ok, enviarlo. Esto lo estoy trabajando con jquery, podrian decirme que codigo usar?

Estos son mis dos inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name="confirmado" id="radio2" value="comprobar">Efectivo</input><br/>
<input type="radio" name="pago" id="radio2" value="comprobar">Con tarjeta</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es que al seleccionar el radio tarjeta, mostra la informacion adicional relacionado a la tarjeta.

Eso puedes hacerlo con el metodo `click()` sobre los 2 radios, si se selecciona tarjeta mostramos el div, sino lo ocultamos:

```js
$("input[name=pago]").click(function(){
  // si es tarjeta, mostramos el div que contiene la inforamcion adicional
  if(this.id == "tarjeta"){
    $("#contenido-tarjeta").show();
  }else{
    $("#contenido-tarjeta").hide();
  }
});

$("button").click(function(){

  if(!$("input[name=pago]").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("enviar informacion del formulario");
  }
  else {
     console.log("informacion valida");
  }  
});
```

```css
#contenido-tarjeta{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pago" id="efectivo" value="comprobar">Efectivo<br/>
<input type="radio" name="pago" id="tarjeta" value="comprobar"/>Con tarjeta

<div id="contenido-tarjeta">

<div>
  Fecha vencimiento <input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
  Codigo <input type="text" />
</div>

</div>
<br>
<button>enviar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!Les habia puesto el mismo nombre antes, toda esa parte funciona bien, sabes como puedo seguir?

Comment: No te entendi. Te falla algo?

Comment: Perdon.. la idea es que al seleccionar pago en efectivo el comprador ya pueda dar click en enviar y ver los datos del comprador. en cambio si da click en con tarjeta... tenga que seguir validando los datos de la tarjeta, como si fuese un subformulario. Necesito, digamos, saber que funcion de jquery haria eso y como?

Comment: Y tienes ya el formulario que se mostrara cuando se seleccione tarjeta?

Comment: Si, asi es, lei en alguna parte que se podria contener ese formulario en una div con la propiedad display none y que cuando el comprador seleccione pago con tarjeta se despliegue. No se que tendria que añadir en el input radio de tarjeta y que codigo en jquery para eso!

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada y dime si es eso lo que buscas.

Comment: bien!! funciona bien, solo que el formulario base que muestra efectivo y tarjeta, aparece el div de los datos de la tarjeta igual, cuando hago click en efectivo desaparece, pero sino... está ahi. puede ser porque no me esté tomando el css, pero ahora reviso,muchas gracias!

Comment: Si hubieses explicado eso antes lo hubiese hecho así. Igual ya tienes la idea cierto?

Comment: aja perdon, yo cuento todo.. Ahora me funciona, lo cambie para que sea asi y funciona perfecto, gracias por encaminarme, saludos!!

Comment: si lo crees conveniente puedes aceptar la respuesta.